# How to make a lightbox with a scroll to top effect when opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

I'm using lightbox_me script which is based on jQuery. Since my lightbox link is at the bottom of my page, I would like to have a scroll to top effect when someone click on a link that opens the lightbox. So basically the lightbox would be shown at the top of the parent page.

I've have setup a clean demo which can be found here : http://lyesdehili.com/LightBox.html

```
$(function () {
    function launch() {
        $('#sign_up').lightbox_me({
            centered: true,
            onLoad: function () {
                $('#sign_up').find('input:first').focus()
            }
        });
    }

    $('#try-1').click(function (e) {
        $("#sign_up").lightbox_me({
            centered: true,
            preventScroll: true,
            onLoad: function () {
                $("#sign_up").find("input:first").focus();
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('table tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('stripe');
});


<div style="width:965px; height:1400px; background:#fff">
    <p>Scroll down the page to find the  lightbox link</p>
</div>
<a class="try sprited" id="try-1" href="#">Click to open lightbox</a>
<div style="display:none; height:350px; width:400px; background:#ccc;" id="sign_up">
    <h3 id="see_id" class="sprited" >Can I see some ID?</h3>
    <span>Please sign in using the form below</span>
    <div id="sign_up_form">
        <label><strong>Username:</strong> <input class="sprited"/></label>
        <label><strong>Password:</strong> <input class="sprited"/></label>
        <div id="actions">
            <a class="close form_button sprited" id="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
            <a class="form_button sprited" id="log_in" href="#">Sign in</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3 id="left_out" class="sprited">Feeling left out?</h3>
    <span>Don't be sad, just <a href="#">click here</a> to sign up!</span>
    <a id="close_x" class="close sprited" href="#">close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#try-1').click(function(e) {
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    $("#sign_up").lightbox_me...; // continue with your code here
});
```

Add a `scrollTop` statement to scroll to the starting of the page.

Comment: I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: body is not defined
$(body).scrollTop(0);

Comment: body needs to be in quotes, like so:

$('body').scrollTop(0);

Comment: @Hiram Hibbard ok updated, not getting any error but it doesn't scroll to the top when clicking on the lightbox link.

Comment: @LyesD this worked for me:

$('#try-1').on('click', function() {
  $('body').scrollTop(0);
});

Comment: Also I tried Anubhav's answer on your page, and that worked for me as well. Perhaps you need to wrap your code in a document ready, or move your script to the end of your body?

Comment: @Hiram Hibbard Would you mind posting an answer that shows exactly where to put that piece of code? Thanks!

Comment: @LyesD I just now looked at the source of your page, and it looks like you're calling the javascript in the correct spot (at the end of your body), so I click the link the modal opens and the page scrolls to the top. Are you actually still seeing an issue?